# Getting error running Bitbucket pipeline for deploying to AWS Cloudformation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy to AWS Cloud Formation using the script. I am using the values present in samconfig.toml. I am able to build it locally but it fails in bitbucket pipeline.

```
step:
          name: Deploy to Cloudformation
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-sam-deploy:1.1.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'my id here'
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'key here'
                AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: 'sessionToken'
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-east-1'
                S3_BUCKET: 's3bucketname'
                STACK_NAME: 'stackname'
                s3_prefix: 'stackname'
                SAM_TEMPLATE: 'template.yaml' 
                capabilities: ['CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM', 'CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND']
                parameter_overrides: ["VPC=\"vpcenteredhere\" VPCEName=\"vpceenteredhere\" MyStageName=\"test\" ApplicationTag=\"project\""]
```

```
✖ Failed to create the stack.
An error occurred (InsufficientCapabilitiesException) when calling the CreateStack operation: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]
ERROR: Failed to get information about stack stackname.
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeStacks operation: Stack with id stackname does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND] as the error describes

that would be,

```
step:
          name: Deploy to Cloudformation
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-sam-deploy:1.1.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'my id here'
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'key here'
                AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: 'sessionToken'
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-east-1'
                S3_BUCKET: 's3bucketname'
                STACK_NAME: 'stackname'
                s3_prefix: 'stackname'
                SAM_TEMPLATE: 'template.yaml' 
                capabilities: ['CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM','CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND']
                parameter_overrides: ["VPC=\"vpcenteredhere\" VPCEName=\"vpceenteredhere\" MyStageName=\"test\" ApplicationTag=\"project\""]
```

Comment: same error again. Thanks. I updated the capabilities. Thanks

Comment: you are still receiving `An error occurred (InsufficientCapabilitiesException) when calling the CreateStack operation: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]` ?

Comment: ```ERROR: Failed to get information about stack stackname.
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeStacks operation: Stack with id stackname does not exist
✖ Failed to create the stack.
An error occurred (InsufficientCapabilitiesException) when calling the CreateStack operation: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]
```